# DialogFlow date intent always triggered over another similar date intent

Tags: dialogflow-es

Good day All,

I have a situation where am building the fulfilment service for the **Flights Pre-built agent in Dialogflow**. Below is a sample interaction in the application.

1. I want a return flight from London to New York - *DialogFlow/Fulfilment back-end picks up the users Ticket-Type[return], To[New York] and From[London] entities.*
2. The fulfilment service responds with - *What date do you plan to travel? E.g next week Monday or 1st of April*
3. User enters Tomorrow - *Dialogflow captures the users Departure Date Entity, we will call this Intent the Departure Intent.*
4. Fulfilment service now goes on to ask -
   *What date do you plan to return? E.g next week Monday or 1st of April, i will call this the Return Intent*
5. User enters next week monday - *Dialogflow will still match the Departure Intent from step 3 and this will cause a response back to the user for the same Return date. But if the user enters i will return next week monday then then the return date intent is matched.*

So my question is how do i make the Return Intent match over the Departure Intent since i have captured the data for Departure and i cannot expect the user to also use the phrase that works with the dates?

### Updated with the Screenshots of affected Intents

1. URL to Logs - https://jsbin.com/wofefivuqo/edit?js
   `sample code`
2. Return Screenshot - 
   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general solution for this is to set a Context once you have the departure date. (For example, you can call it `departure-set`.) You then condition your Intent that gets the return date to say it expects `departure-set` in the Incoming Context. In these cases, it will favor the Intent that has the Context that matches over the one that doesn't (or that has a different Context.)

In your example, you have two Input Contexts, which is fine, but it means that *both* Contexts must be present for the Intent to be triggered. I don't know what the lifespan is for these two Contexts, but I noticed that your `departure-set` Context only has a lifespan of 1, which means it will only be valid on the next response from the user. If you did the same thing for the `flight` Context, then it is likely no longer valid at this point in the conversation.

Comment: Thanks @Prisoner, but maybe am doing something wrong. I have added from the DialogFlow UI a new in-context to the Return intent called **departure-set**, and then from the fulfilment end once the departure date is set i add the **departure-set** in the contextOut parameter of my response payload, now it doesn't even match the departure intent as it used to. Is there anything that am missing???

Comment: That sounds right. Can you update your question to include a screen shot of the two intents in question and, if possible, the JSON your're sending from the departure fulfillment? What does it do when you say the departure date now?

Comment: i have updated the question with the details that you requested. I can send you the github link if you want to run the back-end from your end. However currently the Departure intent is still being matched whenever i enter a date, regardless of whether i have the departure-set context active or not

Comment: it works now, but i didn't have to do this step that i noted in my previous comment - **I have added from the DialogFlow UI a new in-context to the Return intent called departure-set**